# Angular Reactive forms partial form submission

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a long form in an Angular 4 application. Its divided into 4 sections. Each section allows the user to save their progress and come back to finish later. This means that no field is required when saving progress this way. At the end of the form there is a "Submit application" button. When using this button, all fields should be required. 
I have 4 separate components, one for each section and my plan was to submit each section separately but this new requirement changes my plan.

I have a main component like this:

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
    <app-form-1></app-form-1>
    <app-form-2></app-form-2>
    <app-form-3></app-form-3>
    <app-form-4></app-form-4>
</div>
```

and each of the child components looks like this:

```
<form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="field1" class="form-control-label col-md-4 text-md-right">
            Field 1:
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" formControlName="field1" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 1"
                [class.is-invalid]="isFieldInvalid('field1')">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So to be able to submit the for parts together, I'm guessing I would have to move the form up to the main component, and declare each section as a formGroup of that main group. This way I can validate everything when I click "Submit Application". But I now have to be able to save progress on each child component. I could pretend to submit with a regular button that takes the current values and sends them to the server, but this wouldn't trigger other validators like Validators.email and Validators.pattern.

Is there a way I could have partial form submissions that use all the goodness of reactive form validations but allow me to also submit from a parent component?